# How to create nodejs different mysql connection per user

Tags: mysql, node.js, saas

Hello i want to create a SaaS(Software as Service) project, So manage all user organizations on one single database ridiculous So i want to create separate  database per user it is easy manageable. So want to create Node js API with this api user access there associate database.
So how to handle mysql connections per user if you suggest mysql change user runtime it change global connection how to my requirements below diagram show what i want

[this image shows what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQW9O.png)

Comment: Seems simple enough. Create an object with keys being the sockets (or their IDs), and the values the MySQL connections. What have you done so far, or what is your issue ?

Comment: is i run all user connections simultaneously

Comment: You should explain more.. For example... Does every API user has it's own API key (i assume they have).. And does every API user require this own MySQL user? .. As the question is way to broad now..

Comment: Example user1 api is /api/userid1/myorgnization  for user 2 /api/userid2/myorgnization there access only there associate database

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this more an infrastructure question than a nodejs question. As the name Nodejs suggests, especially for larger saas style applications a single node application is a single threaded node which can be part of a larger cluster of nodes.

So based on that. I'd recommend, instead of connecting one node to multiple different databases, run a single node application instance per database, you want to connect to.

There are many ways to approach this. However, I think the simplest way is to containerize your application and use environment variables to set the database connections. When you have your containers you need a way to set your variables and run your different containers. And lastly you will need to route to the correct container.

So:

1. [Containerize a node application with Docker](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)
2. [Deploy with Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)
3. [Routing to correct container](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/routing-applications-in-kubernetes-with-nginx-ingress_594719)

With this method you can spin up one or multiple container for every single client and scale (if implemented correctly) containers based on the amount of resources they use.

Hope this helps getting you started. It is most likely a lot of new information to learn.